# What is the difference between jQuery $.get, $.post & $.getJSON?

Tags: php, jquery, json, post, get

I'm not sure if I should use `$.get` or `$.getJSON.` Which one should I use in this example?

My code:

```
if (isset($_GET['numberofwelds']) && isset($_GET['numberofconwelds']))
{
    // Now we know both values definitely exist, VALIDATE them
    $numwelds = $_GET['numberofwelds'];
    $numconwelds = $_GET['numberofconwelds'];

    if (is_int($numwelds) && is_int($numconwelds))
    {
        // Calculate your total
        $total = $numwelds + $numconwelds;
        echo json_encode($total);


    }
    else
```

Comment: "get, post or JSON" is like asking "apples, bananas or airplanes". You can't compare JSON, a format for serializing hierarchical data, and GET/POST, two methods of making HTTP requests.

Comment: The difference is explained in the documentation. Compare the first paragraph of [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to the first of [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: Also look at the code immediately following the sentence: "This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to"

Comment: @meagar he is talking about jquery methods. I've updated the title.

Comment: Also, GET and POST are really just two different ways to send data to a web server. GET is meant for queries that just retrieve data without changing it, like "I want the web page at http://google.com/", or "give me all of the entries in the database matching this search term". POST is meant for queries that upload data to the server, like "I made a comment on this article; here is my name and the text of the comment." Web servers are free to ignore this pattern, but they shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJson()`, `$.get()` and `$.post` are just aliases for [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) methods with different parameters.

[$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) Loads data from the server using a HTTP GET request. `$.ajax()` equivalent:

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     data: data,
     success: success,
     dataType: dataType
});
```

[$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) Loads data from the server using a HTTP POST request. `$.ajax()` equivalent:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: data,
     success: success,
     dataType: dataType
});
```

[$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request. `$.ajax()` equivalent:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success
});
```

**UPD:**

According to your code, you should use `$.getJSON`. Because of two points:

1. Since you're looking into the **$_GET** variables, you need a **HTTP GET** request
2. Since you're returning **JSON** from the server, you need `dataType` set to **JSON**.

Answer (score 1):

`.getJSON()` is just a wrapper around `.get()`. The major difference is that `.getJSON()` **EXPECTS** that the output from the server is a json string. `.get()` doesn't care what it gets back.

Basically .getjSON is

```
function .getJSON(a,b,c) {
    $.get(a,b,c,'json');
                ^^^^^^--- 4th param of .get tells jquery what data type you're expecting
}
```